# CKEditor баг при загрузке страницы

Tags: html, ckeditor

На странице присутствует 3 поля textarea с CKEditor`ом.

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="field1" cols="50" rows="10" id="field1">Test1</textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="field2" cols="50" rows="10" id="field2">Test2</textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="field3" cols="50" rows="10" id="field3">Test3</textarea>
```

При загрузке страницы текстовая область едитора пустая и в нее нельзя установить курсор (хотя, в полях есть данные, плагин едитора пишет верное количество слов). Так же, отсутствуют значения в плагинах Font Size и Font Name (пустые выпадающие списки). Текст появляется после открытия консоли браузера, но плагины так и остаются пустыми.

Используется кастомный едитор, построенный через http://ckeditor.com/builder. Никаких других плагинов не установлено.
Браузер Chrome, Ubuntu.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: есть возможность выложить эту страничку?

Comment: Интересует полностью HTML?

Comment: @GotFly вы проверяли консоль браузера на наличие ошибок?

Comment: @VenZell Да, разумеется. Если бы были какие-то ошибки, была бы хоть какая-то зацепка, но нет, консоль чистая.